# Need help decrypting an AES encrypted string with Javascript (using crypto-js)

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding, aes, cryptojs

I found that someone had written a demo page that encrypts data on the client side with CryptoJS, which is here:

```
https://github.com/odedhb/AES-encrypt
```

It only has an encrypt function, so I added what I thought would be a decrypt function but end up with completely different text as a result.

My entire test page:

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<br>text:<input id='text' type='text' value='0.1'/>

<br>password:<input id='pass' type='text' value='cool'/>

<br><button onclick="encrypt()">encrypt</button>
<br><button onclick="decrypt()">decrypt</button>


<br>encrypted:<br><input id='result'></input>


<br>decrypted:<br><span id="decode"></span>

<script>
    function encrypt(){

        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(document.getElementById("text").value, document.getElementById("pass").value);
        document.getElementById("result").value = encrypted;
    }

    function decrypt(){

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(document.getElementById("result").value, document.getElementById("pass").value);
        document.getElementById("decode").innerHTML = decrypted;
    }

</script>

</html>
```

On this page, if I enter `Hi I'm Lucas` as the plaintext (no quotes), with a password of `passwd`, I receive back a string of this: `U2FsdGVkX1/S3TobCOdyJ7k7eaBhdFKRpJkDBTpV1D0=`

If i go on to click the decrypt button, I don't get any errors, but i just get a result of `48692049276d204c75636173`.

Obviously, I've done something wrong, and am hoping for an assist here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#plain-text-encryption), it seems the following should work:

```
document.getElementById("decode").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

Comment: That does work and I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed. Thank you!

Comment: Mind if I ask a followup? Trying to figure out how to determine if the decryption failed. If decrypt is given an invalid key, it returns a zero byte string, but on the off chance that some actually encrypted a zero byte string, I'd like to give them that back, rather than give them the same message as if they used the wrong key altogether.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski it looks like the result of `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` is an object that contains a property called `sigBytes` that should be >=0 when the decryption was successful (but it's not documented AFAICS). You can also prefix the plain text with a known string, and after decryption check if the decrypted text has that prefix.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski The `sigBytes` property might be negative, which tells you definitely that either the ciphertext, the key, the IV or the encoding was broken along the way. If it is zero or positive, you cannot be sure that it is the correct key. In roughly 17 out of 256 (random) cases, the key can be wrong, but the property non-negative. You would need to use something like HMAC to produce and authentication tag to check if the ciphertext and the key are valid. See [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/205/13022)

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks for the info :)